# Getting Docker error trying to run script executor

Tags: processmaker

Running scripts in ProcessMaker using javascript script executor was working fine until last week.  Suddenly, started getting the following Docker errors:

"production.ERROR: Script threw return code 125Message: Unable to find image 'processmaker4/executor-bitnami_processmaker-javascript-2:v1.0.0' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for processmaker4/executor-bitnami_processmaker-javascript-2, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied."

Tried upgrading PM AMI from version 4.1 to latest 4.2.3-5, but still getting error. Wondering if something changed with backend container repository. I did not change anything, PM builds the docker command with repository URL and API token automatically.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: the error claim you have to login, so you can try `docker login {artifactory_link}`

Comment: @George thanks for the reply.  ProcessMaker automatically builds the docker command to execute the script in a temporary docker container (shown below).  This was working until last week without having to do anything with docker:

/usr/bin/docker run --rm -e HOST_URL='http://hostip' -e API_TOKEN=eyJ0e....sW9ag -e API_HOST=http://hostip/api/1.0 -e APP_URL=http://hostip -e API_SSL_VERIFY=1 --shm-size=256m  -v /opt/bitnami/processmaker/storage/app/scripts/putSR2Wm9:/opt/executor/data.json .... processmaker4/executor-bitnami_processmaker-javascript-2:v1.0.0 /bin/sh /opt/executor/run.sh 2>&1"

Comment: Are you behind a company selfhosted docker registry? As @George mentioned I would suggest yu have a look at the authentication process ProcessMaker is using and look for auth problems there.

Comment: Hi @RenéJahn, not behind a company self hosted docker registry.  Just running on a server in AWS.  Was working perfectly, then stopped.  Just to reiterate, I do not generate the docker command - it is done automatically by the script executor.  Something must have changed on the docker registry where processmaker hosts their images.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not about docker login.
The image PRocess maker uses is not on dockerhub or anywhere else.
It is built by your Process maker
In process maker Go to Admin -> Script Executors and open the executor you want. Click the build and save button. You will notice it then runs a docker build command.

This might help https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/processmaker/configuration/install-script-executors/